# iOS Build process using terminal

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode8

I have been using a script to generate my IPA for Enterprise as well as store. After I updated to xcode 8.3 the script stopped working. Following is the line where it's throwing the error.

```
my $output = `xcodebuild -exportArchive -exportFormat IPA -archivePath \"$schemeArchivePath.xcarchive\" -exportPath \"$schemeIPAPath\" -exportWithOriginalSigningIdentity`;
```

Comment: Could you add some more details on the actual error, please?

Comment: @ Jens Meder I get the following error - 
xcodebuild: error: invalid option '-exportFormat'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting with Xcode 8.3 there are some changes to the process when using `xcodebuild` for the creation of IPA files. Basically, you need to create a plist file that contains the relevant options for IPA export. Instead of using `exportFormat IPA` you now need to use `-exportOptionsPlist config.plist` (given that you call the file `config.plist`).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>method</key>
    <string>app-store</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

If you want to know all available plist options you can just type `xcodebuild -h` in a Terminal.

Hope that helps.